# Paypal API payments Pro transactions not showing shipping details

Tags: api, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

So Paypal receives our payments, no issue there. It is just that the payment details, and the receipt emails that Paypal sends/provides do not include the shipping info. user name address etc.

We are trying to mimic the old sales flow coding that the old Joomla system was using. THOSE email receipts from Paypal do include shipping details for the customer.

We have no idea what we are not doing that the old coding was doing. we send various customer fields and shipping detail fields, yet no shipping details show up. we are using Do DirectPayments method. Maybe we need to use another method? maybe thee is something else we are not sending.

Again, the transaction details used to show shipping details of user and now they do not.

any help appreciated. Im pasting the code below:

```
function DoPayment()
{
        global $api_username,$api_password,$api_signature,$api_version,$api_endpoint;

        $expdate = $_POST['exp_month'] . $_POST['exp_year'];
        // Store request params in an array
        $request_params = array(
             'METHOD' => 'DoDirectPayment', 
             'USER' => $api_username, 
             'PWD' => $api_password, 
             'SIGNATURE' => $api_signature, 
             'VERSION' => $api_version, 
             'PAYMENTACTION' => 'Sale',                     
             'IPADDRESS' => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],
             'CREDITCARDTYPE' => $_POST['card_type'], 
             'ACCT' => $_POST['card_number'],                       
             'EXPDATE' => $expdate,             
             'CVV2' => $_POST['cvv2'], 
             'CARDHOLDERNAME' => $_POST['cardholder_firstname'], 
             'STREET' => $_POST['card_street'], 
             'STREET2' => $_POST['card_street2'], 
             'CITY' => $_POST['card_city'], 
             'STATE' => $_POST['card_state'],                   
             'COUNTRYCODE' => $_POST['card_country'], 
             'ZIP' => $_POST['card_zip'], 
             'AMT' => $_POST['amount'], 
             'CURRENCYCODE' => 'USD', 
             'EMAIL' => $_POST['email'], 
             'PHONE' => $_POST['phone'], 
             'DESC' => $_POST['comments'],
             'SHIPTONAME' => $_POST['cardholder_firstname'],
             'SHIPTOSTREET' => $_POST['card_street'],
             'SHIPTOSTREET2' => $_POST['card_street2'],
             'SHIPTOCITY' => $_POST['card_city'],
             'SHIPTOSTATE' => $_POST['card_state'],
             'SHIPTOPHONENUM' => $_POST['phone']
        );

        // Loop through $request_params array to generate the NVP string.
        $nvp_string = '';
        foreach($request_params as $var=>$val)
        {
            $nvp_string .= '&'.$var.'='.urlencode($val);    
        } 
        // Send NVP string to PayPal and store response
        $curl = curl_init();
                        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
                        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
                        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
                        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $api_endpoint);
                        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
                        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $nvp_string);

        $result = curl_exec($curl);
        //echo //$result.'<br /><br />';
        curl_close($curl);

        return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so it seems the above works and the shipping details is actually appearing since im using the shipping paramaters, so im closing this.